# Maximum timeOut for NSMutableRequest & NSURLConnection

Tags: iphone, ipad, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

What is the maximum timeout interval I can use in my application. I m using following method.

```
(id)initWithURL:(NSURL *)URL cachePolicy:(NSURLRequestCachePolicy)cachePolicy timeoutInterval:(NSTimeInterval)timeoutInterval;
```

I m using GET Method.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a max. Just try with 9999999 with an URL that doesn't respond, step by step, then check if a maximum exists...

Comment: Why do you need a very large timeout, just go with something like 300

Answer (score 3):

`NSTimeInterval` data type is typedef of **double** data type, so the maximum time out value supported is the value that is maximum for **double** data type.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take into account that HTTP uses TCP. TCP connections are not controlled only by your application, there are also many routers and firewalls in between your application and the server.

I took a look into a typical firewall documentation just to see what is the default timeout for TCP connections.

For CISCO it is one hour.

http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/asa91/configuration/firewall/asa_91_firewall_config/conns_connlimits.html#42354

So maybe you should consider this information when deciding on maximum connection timeout.

Also see section 5.5 here : https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6202
They claim that the best practice is 30 seconds.